# looking for open source for js parser that support IntelliSense ( .js + .ts files )

Tags: javascript, typescript, parsing, intellisense

do you familiar with any open-source that support .js file + typescript (with some definitions)
that parse files + have any API for IntelliSense ?
After the parsing, I want to send parser any member + '.'  and then get a list of method (like IntelliSense on editor support)?

I want to integrate it and show member list dialog on my editor

```
// exmple : 
class User {
    myTest() {
    alert(this.name);
    }
}

let user = new User();
user.   // I will get here method myTest()
```

Regards
Oren

Comment: Hi @orenga, there are lots of open source parsers for JS and TS. If you're looking for syntax highlighting and intellisense then you should find many options per editor. If this is to build your own then I'd suggest searching online for a parser that fits your criteria.

Comment: yes, i want to build for my own, 
I see parser but I don't see any API to get IntelliSense (member list )  per object that user type on editor

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, there is [V8](https://v8.dev/) — the JS engine used in Chrome & Node, developed by Google & open sourced. [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/v8/v8) is also available. [Documentation](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-13.2/).

Comment: i see that when the V8 compile() failed 
I can't ask for member list, Is that correct,?
or there is another way to get them even when js not valid like in the example when I type user.

Answer (score 0):

For es6/typescript, typescript language server - https://github.com/sourcegraph/javascript-typescript-langserver
For es5, tern js is one library that you can check out - https://ternjs.net/